# Degrading apk version in play store

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I have upload one app in play store with version 1.
You & me install that apk with version 1 from play store
after some time owner release the app with version 2 then you install the version 2  & I am still using the version 1
Now owner have degrade the version from 2 to 1 version

In this scenario 
Your application with version 2 will work or crash?
My application with version 1 will work or crash?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say.  The app itself won't suddenly stop working. However, there are two factors to consider:

1)If they rolled back, its probably because something was badly broken with v2.  So it won't break because they rolled back, but it may break because its buggy.

2)If the app communicates with a server, that server may also have been rolled back and not work with v2.  In that case unknown breaks can occur.